# Calling apex with multiple parameter where the parameter is coming from input field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire

I have a apex class

```
public static List<Customer_information__c> gettingRecords(String detail, Date starti, Date endi, String comboData)
```

And i am wiring this from js

```
@wire(gettingRecords,{detail:'$queryTermPassed'}, {starti:'$dateStart'}, {endi:'$dateEnd'}, {comboData:'$comboData'})
 records
```

Now I want that if my user have not passed dateStart field or dateEnd field or comboData then also my apex function should be called by queryTermPassed or vice-versa.

Like if I am passing all the field then I am getting output but by passing only one field the apex is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters object is *one* object. Do not provide one parameter object per parameter:

```
@wire(gettingRecords,{
  detail: '$queryTermPassed', 
  starti: '$dateStart', 
  endi: '$dateEnd', 
  comboData: '$comboData'})
records;
```

The line breaks here are provided for legibility, but not required.